# how to use golden ratio and fibonacci to improve a shape's form?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, shapes, design-principles, symbolism

I'm trying to improve my skills and make this X look more appealing, the logo icon is an X, and it's related to tracking technology, I'm trying to it more interesting[image: X]

like these

[image: Apple's logo]
[image: Evernote's logo]

Comment: Hi Daniel, just so you know, the apple logo was not actually designed with the grid in your example. Many design critics of these iconic logos have applied grids arbitrarily, after-the-fact despite no such grid being used in their creation. Using the golden ratio can give you direction when making decisions but bear in mind that the golden ratio is *everywhere* if you look hard enough! Another tip that I find helpful is the scale test - see how small you can print your logo before it becomes illegible. This will help you decide on your logo's proportions/cuts/gaps/etc. Hope this helps

Comment: Do you want to stick with the X? It's quite generic. What's the name of the company?

Comment: I can't say the name and I can't change the X. Is there a way to improve the form? any suggestions? The X should resemble a target, I've had a circle around but the circle didn't work with the X (it did metaphorically but not in terms of design)

Comment: @DanielVianna That's fine. Hmm, can you give us more details? Is this telecoms, advertising, search trends, visitor counts, criminal prevention? What do you think of any of these 3 http://imgur.com/ZaQ3vyC

Comment: It looks good for me. But it's a real-time tracking technology. The industry is hardware. just imagine a technology that can track where a person or object is located in real-time. Originally as I said, the X had a circle around it, the circle with the X represented the "cross hair" . This is the old logo: http://imgur.com/e03Jh1L

Comment: I think an X will always be quite abstract... what about a location icon? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=golden+ratio+logos&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=956&tbm=isch&imgil=ELf9z3rUJgiwpM%253A%253Bhli6RWWqlDzMiM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.youtube.com%25252Fwatch%25253Fv%2525253D1aH9wO9_JV8&source=iu&pf=m&fir=ELf9z3rUJgiwpM%253A%252Chli6RWWqlDzMiM%252C_&usg=__ltPmkA8-tbLhawzQIJrMurCMJ3k%3D&ved=0ahUKEwiVrbD3v4fMAhUKuhQKHWglBSwQyjcILw&ei=IRMMV9WYJ4r0UujKlOAC

Comment: I can't change the X, only put the X inside something, that idea was tried before and it was rejected, the X is part of the name and I only try to tweak it in order to get approval (coming up with a brand new idea is out of question unfortunately)  . Question: is there any shape that resembles a tracking aim which  would work with a X ? I've tried putting the x on a triangle but it didn't work visually

Comment: Use the golden ratio swirl as a way to suggest movement? And the X in the center to suggest homing in on the focal point.

Answer (score 1):

The golden ratio is 1×1.6, you could make the X 160 tall and 100 wide, but it won't be interesting yet. Exes are symmetrical so you're going to have to warp it to make it dynamic like above. I recommend finding a good x in a font or drawing one, then playing with it to see what's possible. Separate and offset each leg, round corners or no, put it in the rotate tool. Place it over the golden grid and line things up. Look up "X logo" in Google images and get ideas. Play end experiment, make copies and try new effects.